# react setState function is not workin

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I am new at react and
I have been trying to apply event handling in react but facing some Problem on onclick event.
When the button "show me of germany" is called the Page then stuck to loading only ...

Here is the code i have written ..

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { articles: [],
                isLoaded:false ,
                country:'us'
                }
       
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        const APIurl = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.state.country}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
        fetch(APIurl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    articles: json.articles,
                    isLoaded:true
                })
            })
    }
   // function to change the state
    change()
    {
        this.setState({
            articles: [],
            isLoaded:false ,
            country:"de"

        })
    }   
   
    render() {
      const { isLoaded,articles } = this.state;
      if(!isLoaded)
      {
          return (<h1>Loading....</h1>)
      }
     
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <button onClick={this.change}>show me of germany</button>
                <ul>
                    {articles.map(item=>(
                           <News item={item}/>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
       );
   }
}
export default App;
```

Hope you understood the problem

Comment: Well the only thing that the button does is call the function that clears the data and sets `isLoading` state to false. If you want to load new data you have to do the Ajax request again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do request again.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      country:'us'
    }
       
    this.change = this.change.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData(this.state.country);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { country: prevCountry } = prevState;
    const { country: nextCountry } = this.state;

    if (prevCountry !== nextCountry) {
      fetchData(nextCountry);
    }
  }

  change() {
    this.setState({ country: 'de' });
  }

  fetchData(country) {
    this.setState({ articles: [], isLoaded: false });

    fetch(
      `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${country}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(({ articles }) => {
        this.setState({ articles, isLoaded: true });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
   
  render() {
    //...
  }
}

export default App;
```